# Is Zayed et al.’s revision of Orthornavirae robust?

Tags: genetics, virology, rna, phylogenetics

Zayed et al. (April 7, 2022) in *Science* [“Cryptic and abundant marine viruses at the evolutionary origins of Earth’s RNA virome”](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abm5847) report several major hitherto-unknown Ribovirial phyla:

[image: New Orthornaviran phyla]

The two most sampled, *Taraviricota* and *Arctiviricota*, had the lowest normalized abundances.

To mitigate issues of subjectivity, their RdRp-based phylogenetic analysis was developed to recapitulate [the established ICTV-accepted taxonomy](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/MBio.02329-18.F1.large.jpg) (97% agreement).  Their new tree shows a very different early evolutionary history, for example splitting *Duplornaviricota* into 3 distant phyla:

[image: New Orthornavirae phylogenetic tree]

Are these findings robust?  The unknown megataxa and the revision of Orthornavirae?

Comment: Do you really think that there is someone on this list who has read and is better able to assess this paper than the referees assigned to it by Science? I presume you feel it important — I have no idea — but if it is I’m afraid you will have to wait either for direct responses to the journal, or future publications citing it. This is a question and answer site  about biology, not a journal club.

Comment: Can you identify the evidence supporting alternate tree topologies? If you show that evidence here we might be able to judge it.

Comment: Paper certainly looks robust - you would need to dig out the original data and analyse for yourself if you wished to compare. You can find the annotated data here: https://datacommons.cyverse.org/browse/iplant/home/shared/iVirus/ZayedWainainaDominguez-Huerta_RNAevolution_Dec2021

Comment: @David Sometimes in phylogenetics the reviewers of science are just a joke (see the [Omicron evolved in west africa retracted paper](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.add8737) where the non-omicron raw reads were just contaminated with later omicron strains)

Comment: The main difficulty here is that it is risky to feed mafft directly with so distant RdRp, the resulting alignment will be a mess for sure. You can try running a MCMC optimizing both the tree and the alignment (after subsampling the dataset) and see if the deep branches topology stays comparable.